# dynamixel no motor found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i had connected OpenCM9.04 with MX-64 motors. tried this [dynamixel tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus).after this step,

> roslaunch my_dynamixel_tutorial controller_manager.launch

i get this error:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dynamixel_manager/namespace: dxl_manager
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/baud_rate: 57600
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/max_motor_id: 25
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/min_motor_id: 1
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/port_name: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/update_rate: 20
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.9

NODES
  /
    dynamixel_manager (dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3297]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 68403748-7b49-11e4-b3a3-ac7289859e59
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3310]
started core service [/rosout]
process[dynamixel_manager-2]: started with pid [3327]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:92: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.motor_states_pub = rospy.Publisher('motor_states/%s' % self.port_namespace, MotorStateList)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:93: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.diagnostics_pub = rospy.Publisher('/diagnostics', DiagnosticArray)
[INFO] [WallTime: 1417651594.990743] pan_tilt_port: Pinging motor IDs 1 through 25...
[FATAL] [WallTime: 1417651597.100174] pan_tilt_port: No motors found.
================================================================================REQUIRED process [dynamixel_manager-2] has died!
process has died [pid 3327, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py __name:=dynamixel_manager __log:=/home/pavithran/.ros/log/68403748-7b49-11e4-b3a3-ac7289859e59/dynamixel_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/pavithran/.ros/log/68403748-7b49-11e4-b3a3-ac7289859e59/dynamixel_manager-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[dynamixel_manager-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

i also tried changing the baudrate to 1000000.

how do i overcome this error?

Thank you...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198853/dynamixel-no-motor-found/) by [pavi.hmd](https://answers.ros.org/users/21021/pavi.hmd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You did not mention whether you configured the servos, so I thought it'd be worth mentioning.

Each servo stores a set of parameters internally. You must configure (or at least check the configuration of) every servo separately before you attempt to communicate with them.

There are 2 key parameters you must ensure are correct in order to communicate with the servos.

The first parameter is the `baud rate`. You are trying to connect to the servos at 57600 bps, and you said you also tried 1000000 bps. You must ensure all servos are configured to use the same baud rate, and use that value when you load the node.

The second parameter is the `servo ID` (which should be unique to each servo). You are attempting to communicate with servos which IDs range from 1 to 25. It could be that your servos were configured with IDs out of this range.

Configuring the servos:

You may use [RoboPlus](http://support.robotis.com/en/software/roboplus_main.htm) (on Windows), which is the official software from Robotis.

Alternatively (if you know the parameter values currently configured), you can also change the servos IDs, as well as set the desired parameter values using [these ROS nodes](https://github.com/arebgun/dynamixel_motor/tree/master/dynamixel_driver/scripts).

Related question: [ClamArm using Dynamixel Motors: No Motors Found](http://answers.ros.org/question/76243/clamarm-using-dynamixel-motors-no-motors-found/)

I hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavi.hmd](https://answers.ros.org/users/21021/pavi.hmd/) on 2014-12-04**:
Thanks for the reply. Yes,i configured the servos with baud rate and id . But still no luck. Should i use usb2dynamixel or is OpenCM9.04B enough for this tutorial?

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-12-08**:
I have used the USB2Dynamixel and a simple USB to RS485 converter I assembled myself. They both worked fine for me... :-|

**Comment by [Wine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22056/wine/) on 2015-04-01**:
bad luck, I tried both USb2dynamixel and DIY usb-rs485 converter, no one works for me...... and also roboplus cannot find my mx-64ar through all the bps searching.... is that mean my servo is a defective ?

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2015-04-24**:
It does sound like your servo might be defective. Have you got another servo to test?

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-10-15**:
I have same issue, with arbotix-m controller no motor detected when I run

```
roslaunch dynamixel_tutorials controller_manager.launch
```